# Nginx server static files with try_files under location

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configurations:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location /severbat {

        root /root/severbat/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /swagger {
        root /root/av/swagger-ui-dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

}
```

And I files **/root/severbat/dist/index.html** and **/root/av/swagger-ui-dist/index.html** exist. But if I open url http://localhost/severbat I see nginx greetings page instead of index.html

However if I serve files under **/** it works:

```
location / {
    root /root/severbat/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

**nginx-acesss.log**:

```
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 trying to use file: "/swagger" "/root/av/swagger-ui-dist/swagger"
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 trying to use file: "/index.html" "/root/av/swagger-ui-dist/index.html"
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 internal redirect: "/index.html?"
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 rewrite phase: 1
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 test location: "/severbat"
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 test location: "/api"
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 using configuration ""
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 http cl:-1 max:5242880
...
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 content phase: 17
2018/10/03 09:32:44 [debug] 23052#23052: *519 http filename: "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to ServerFault.

I think your problem is that NGINX *appends* the matched `location` to the specified `root`, so when you enter, for example, `http://localhost/swagger` NGINX looks for the directory `/root/av/swagger-ui-dist/swagger` and doesn't find it.

That's how the `root` directive works in NGINX

You might want to use the `alias` directive instead:

```
location /severbat {
    alias /root/severbat/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}

location /swagger {
    alias /root/av/swagger-ui-dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

Comment: Nginx respond with 404. If location is `/` configuration `/index.html` doesn't work as well

Comment: @deathangel908 looks like the problem was elsewhere. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is NOT a valid answer! Look at "Using the try_files $uri directive with alias": https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/ As you can see this is not going to work as expected.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, and switching to `alias` also gives me a 404. Any updates on a solution to this issue?